# Update payment method pane with ajax

Tags: commerce, ajax

I have the coupon pane, the order review and the payment info panes all on the same checkout page. When I add a coupon, an ajax callback is fired and the order summary is automatically updated to reflect the coupon, but the payment info pane is not updated.

I have a rule for two payment methods. One for non-zero order totals, and one for zero total orders. If I add a coupon that brings the total to zero, and then refresh the whole page, the rule action does apply and enab;es my 'free' payment method. However, it only works with a full refresh.

Is there a way to get the payment info pane to refresh during the coupon add ajax callback?

Otherwise, my customers see a zero total and they still see the payment info that requires them to put in a credit card to finish the order.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to trigger a page refresh from the ajax?  I'm not entirely sure if you would be able to load the individual pane.